# which thread processes messages of a spesific hwnd

Tags: c++, winapi, synchronization, message-queue

I have two threads and I call CreateWindowEx function from different processes. The two threads are MainThread and Action.dlu.

Action.dlu creates a window and holds a buffer associated with the window. Whenever I resize the window, window messages are acumulated untill I process and deleted them from queue with the fallowing lines.

```
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, mHWnd, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Action.dlu uses the buffer associated with the window so I process messages when I finish using buffers. However, when I create the window from MainThread, WM_SIZE message gets immediately triggered. I mean it doesn't wait for me to process messages. My WNDPROC calback function gets called from MainThread. Is there a way to make a specific process the owner of the window ? This way I can keep processing messages wherever I want.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I think you're using the words "thread" and "process" interchangeably, which makes it very difficult to understand what you're asking. Do you have two threads in a single process, each creating a window? Are you using MFC or some other framework?

Comment: If you must proceed along this path, look at [message-only windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599(v=vs.85).aspx#message_only).  They don't have visuals associated with them, so they're pretty good for this sort of thing.